# Loop through an object of objects and extract key value that equals something specific?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, filter

I am trying to avoid dependencies such as loaddash (_.filter) and use pure javascript.

Basically I have an object of objects, and I need to loop through and filter out all that dont have a parent_id of a specific value.

```
var filterBy = 50
var obj = {
  256: {
    name: john
    parent_id: 50
  },
  341: {
    name: dwit
    parent_id: 50
  },
  398: {
    name: ryan
    parent_id: 30
  },
  421: {
    name: jack
    parent_id: 50
  }
}
```

with the result being

```
var filteredOBJ = {
  256: {
    name: john
    parent_id: 50
  },
  343: {
    name: dwit
    parent_id: 50
  },
  421: {
    name: jack
    parent_id: 50
  }
}
```

Comment: Would be nice to see some code

Comment: There's a typo in the results, object `341` should be there not `343`

Comment: Look into `Object.keys` and `Object.values`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like the loadash approach, but want to use javascript, [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on the `Object.entries()` will give you nice functional approach, although the above `forEach` solutions probably win for readabilty.

```js
var filterBy = 50
var obj = {256: {name: 'john',parent_id: 50},341: {name: 'dwit',parent_id: 50},398: {name: 'ryan',parent_id: 30},421: {name: 'jack',parent_id: 50}}

let r = Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [k, v]) => 
        v.parent_id === filterBy 
        ? Object.assign(a, {[k]: v})
        : a, {})

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 const result = {};
 for(const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if(val.parent_id === filterBy) {
       result[key] = val;
    }
  }
```

Just turn what you described into code and you're done.

Comment: @dan cause you can't filter an object. And I don't like that object -> 2d array -> `filter` -> object approach, as it overcomplucates things just to use *one* array method

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of a simple filter in ES6 :

```
let myObj = {
  256: {
    name: "john",
    parent_id: 50
  },
  341: {
    name: "dwit",
    parent_id: 50
  },
  398: {
    name: "ryan",
    parent_id: 30
  },
  421: {
    name: "jack",
    parent_id: 50
  }
}

let result = {};
Object.entries(myObj).forEach( ([key, value]) => {
  if(key != 398)  // condition over keys 
    result[key] = value;
})
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a counterpart [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) so you can use vanilla javascript [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Just convert object to entries, filter and convert back from entries to object.

```js
const filterBy = 50
const obj = {256: {name: 'john',parent_id: 50}, 341: {name: 'dwit',parent_id: 50}, 398: {name: 'ryan',parent_id: 30}, 421: {name: 'jack',parent_id: 50}}

const filteredObj = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj).filter(
    ([key, value]) => 
      value.parent_id === filterBy
  )
)

console.log(filteredObj)
```